# spring integration sftp not able to move file to processed in remote folder

Tags: spring, sftp, spring-integration

I am able to copy the file from remote machine to local but not able to move the file to processed folder in remote server.

```
<bean id="sftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
<property name="host" value="test.com"/>
<property name="user" value="test"/>
<property name="password" value="test123"/>
<property name="port" value="22"/>
</bean>

<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="publishToSFTPChannel" />

<sftp:inbound-channel-adapter local-directory="#{articlesLocalDirectory}"  filename-pattern="*.xml"  channel="publishToSFTPChannel" session-factory="sftpSessionFactory" remote-directory="#{articlesRemoteDirectory}">
<int:poller fixed-rate="12000"/>
</sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>


<file:outbound-channel-adapter id="moveProcessedFile"
session-factory="sftpSessionFactory" 
channel="publishToSFTPChannel"
directory="#{articlesRemoteDirectory}/processed"
delete-source-files="true"  />
```

I am not able to move the file to processed folder in remote ftp

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You want to download file from SFTP server to local directory, and then move the same file to another directory on same SFTP server? Your configuration won't work for that. You have file outbound adapter, it will only copy file to a local directory, not remote, and you don't need `session-factory` on it. Please describe exactly what are you trying to do, because what you state in the problem and what I see in configuration are different things.

Comment: @Dmitry Thanks again. What I am trying to achieve is I want to copy the file from FTP to local directory.After copying that file I need to  move the file in FTP to processed folder in the same remote directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Gary Russell that the best way would be to use `mv` command. But if you want to use current release, you can try configuration similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
   xmlns:sftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp/spring-integration-sftp-2.2.xsd">

<bean id="sftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="localhost"/>
    <property name="user" value="user01"/>
    <property name="password" value="abc123"/>
    <property name="port" value="990"/>
</bean>

<int:channel id="sftpChannel"/>

<sftp:inbound-channel-adapter local-directory="/tmp/test" filename-pattern="*.xml"
                              channel="sftpChannel" session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
                              remote-directory="/">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="5000"/>
</sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

<sftp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="sftpChannel" session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
                               remote-directory="/processed"/>

</beans>
```

`inbound-channel-adapter` downloads the file from SFTP server to a local directory and `outbound-channel-adapter` places copy of that file in /processed folder on SFTP server.

Note that this is definitely not the best option, since you have to reupload your file to SFTP.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to rename a file on the remote machine, the [upcoming 3.0 release](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway) now has a `mv` command on the (s)ftp outbound gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this link:

[http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmbhelp/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.etools.mft.doc%2Fac55462_.htm](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmbhelp/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac55462_.htm)
may be help to move file on remote server...

Comment: I need sftp in spring integration